# How to add data labels to a Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've created a pie chart using the Google Chart API but am unable to control which data labels are added. I'd like to be able to add a label for each slice of the pie. Can anyone provide any insight on how to go about doing this?

Code for the chart below:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Resource', 'Percentage'],
          ['Video',     517],
          ['Download',      13],
          ['Tool',      13],
          ['Video and Download',  15],
          ['Video and Tool', 59],
          ['Download Video and Tool',    5]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: '',
      is3D: 'true',
      colors: ['592C81', '799A3D', '863375', '5B5B5B', '004A97', 'B8BABD' ]
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there's not enough room in each slice, looks like the best you can do is add

```
 legend: { position: 'labeled' }
```

to your options.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u3jk101y/).