# How can I enable "Data Labels" in a Google Sheet via the API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

As you can see from the image below, towards the bottom under the Series options there is an option called "Data Labels".  How can I enable that option as I create a chart through the API?  FYI, I'm using the .NET API.

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheets Chart Editor]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add data labels to a Google Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814107/how-to-add-data-labels-to-a-google-chart)?

Comment: @ADW I don’t think so, that looks like the JS API for the front end, not the .NET/REST API.

Comment: When I checked the difference 2 sample charts with and without `Data Labels` using the method of spreadsheets.get, I could confirm that the same responses were returned. By this, unfortunately, I thought that it cannot check `Data Labels` using Sheets API.

Comment: @Tanaike Good idea on using the `get` API method to try and find the property... too bad it didn't pan out :(

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. So in the current stage, unfortunately, I think that there are no methods for achieving this using Sheets API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not currently supported.  Here is the feature request for anyone waiting for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124813113

Answer (score 1):

According to issuetracker mentioned above, at least since May 14, 2021, this feature has been implemented. You can find it here: [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#DataLabel)