# Cannot add data labels to chart in addChart request by Google Sheets API

Tags: charts, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to generate chart via Google Sheets API using service account. Everything is ok, but data labels didn't shows up on chart.

I have just added **dataLabel** object to addChart request, but received zero effect:

```
"dataLabel": {
    "type": 'DATA',
    "textFormat": {
          "bold": true,
     },
     "placement": 'INSIDE_END',
},
```

Here is my full request:

```
const insertChartToSpreadsheet = (fileID) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let spreadsheetID = fileID;
        let requests = [];
        requests.push({
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 100,
                    //"startColumnIndex": 0,
                    //"endColumnIndex": 30
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "textFormat": {
                            "fontSize": 13,
                        },
                    },
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.fontSize"
            },
        });
        // set header text format as Bold and 18 pt
        requests.push({
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 2,
                    //"startColumnIndex": 0,
                    //"endColumnIndex": 30
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "textFormat": {
                            "fontSize": 18,
                            "bold": true
                        },
                    },
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
            },
        });
        // set subheader text format as Bold and 15 pt
        requests.push({
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "startRowIndex": 3,
                    "endRowIndex": 4,
                    //"startColumnIndex": 0,
                    //"endColumnIndex": 30
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "textFormat": {
                            "fontSize": 15,
                            "bold": true
                        },
                    },
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
            },
        });
        // set client data as Bold
        requests.push({
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "startRowIndex": 5,
                    "endRowIndex": 10,
                    "startColumnIndex": 3,
                    "endColumnIndex": 5
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "textFormat": {
                            "fontSize": 13,
                            "bold": true
                        },
                    },
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
            },
        });
        // set 1st column width as 20px
        requests.push({
            "updateDimensionProperties": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": 1
                },
                    "properties": {
                    "pixelSize": 20
                },
                "fields": "pixelSize"
            }
        });
        // set 4st column width as 150px
        requests.push({
            "updateDimensionProperties": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "startIndex": 3,
                    "endIndex": 4
                },
                    "properties": {
                    "pixelSize": 150
                },
                "fields": "pixelSize"
            }
        });
        // set bold factors Values
        requests.push({
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "startRowIndex": 33,
                    "endRowIndex": 45,
                    "startColumnIndex": 4,
                    "endColumnIndex": 5
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "textFormat": {
                            "fontSize": 13,
                            "bold": true
                        },
                    },
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
            },
        });
        // set bold test date
        requests.push({
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 0,
                    "startRowIndex": 5,
                    "endRowIndex": 6,
                    "startColumnIndex": 7,
                    "endColumnIndex": 8
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "textFormat": {
                            "fontSize": 13,
                            "bold": true
                        },
                    },
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
            },
        });
        requests.push({
            "addChart": {
                "chart": {
                    "chartId": 1,
                    "spec": {
                        "titleTextFormat": {
                            
                        },
                        "basicChart": {
                            "chartType": "BAR",
                            "axis": [
                                {
                                    "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                                },
                                {
                                    "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                                }
                            ],
                            "domains": [
                                {
                                    "domain": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 33,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 45,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 1,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 2
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                    },
                                }
                            ],
                            "series": [
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": 0,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 33,
                                                    "endRowIndex": 45,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 4,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 5
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "targetAxis": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                                    "dataLabel": {
                                        "type": 'DATA',
                                        "textFormat": {
                                            "bold": true,
                                        },
                                        "placement": 'INSIDE_END',
                                    },
                                }
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                    "position": {
                        "overlayPosition": {
                            "anchorCell": {
                                "sheetId": 0,
                                "rowIndex": 11,
                                "columnIndex": 1
                            },
                            "offsetXPixels": 0,
                            "offsetYPixels": 0,
                            "widthPixels": 800,
                            "heightPixels": 450
                        },
                        //"newSheet": false
                    },
                    "border": {
                        "color": {
                            "red": 1,
                            "green": 1,
                            "blue": 1,
                            "alpha": 0
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        const batchUpdateRequest = { requests };
        sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
            spreadsheetId: spreadsheetID,
            resource: batchUpdateRequest,
        }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(result.data.spreadsheetId)
            }
        });
    })
};
```

Am I missing something? According to this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124813113), than I found under this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628169/how-can-i-enable-data-labels-in-a-google-sheet-via-the-api)  this feature has been implemented not so long time ago.

Comment: Can you share an actual sample sheet that when this above request is run, it doesn't show the labels? Maybe there's something within the document that causes the issue. It may be data or some settings of the chart.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13HWmjqbCuLGGbXAfwXcZEO0-7LN5OhEyIwTuorQBlJo/edit?usp=sharing). But actually I can add this data labels manually in right panel when editing chart. So, I think it should work... But it doesn't